# With react-select, add classNames onto "multiValue" and "option" elements

Tags: javascript, react-select

We are looking to add classes to various elements in the `react-select` select component. We have the following code to create a multi-select:

```
const CustomMultiLabel = (option) => {
    return (
        <span className={`value-${option.data.value}`}>
            {option.data.shortLabel}
        </span>
    );
};

const scopeMultiSelect =
    (<Select
        className='cbb-select cbb-scope-multi-select'
        styles={blackSelectStyles()}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        value={multiScope}
        isMulti
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={multiScopeOptions}
        components={{ MultiValueLabel: CustomMultiLabel }}
        getOptionProps={(option) => {
            return {
                className: option.data.value
            };
        }}
    />);
```

And the following HTML is rendered:

[image]

We are struggling with classes in 2 ways:

- currently the class-name `value-${option.data.value}` (e.g. 'value-l5g') is being added to the  element, but we need this to be added to 's parent , the  with className `-multiValue`.
- no classes are being added onto the `options` in the `menuList`, however we would like classes added here as well.

Is it possible to modify our code to add classes into the correct places?

**Edit:** we are using react-select version 3.1.0, but it looks like a `classNames` prop was introduced in version 5.7.0... we are trying to upgrade to give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to `v5.7.0`, adding the following to the main select did the trick:

```
<Select
    classNames={{
        option: d => `our-option-${d.data.value}`,
         multiValue: d => `our-multivalue-${d.data.value}`
    }}
    ...
/>
```